# Height of div automatically adjusted to inner elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, height

I have the following html:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="..."/>
    <p>Heading</p>
</div>
```

I want this behaviour:

- If there is no image (no <img> tag) the p should dictate the size of the .container.
- If there is an image, but the p is taller the .container should be as tall as the p.
- If the image is taller the .container should be as tall as the image and the p should "grow" from the bottom of .container and up depending on the amount of text in it (like position:absolute; bottom:0 inside a position:relative box).
- The p should have a background that should be semi transparent so you can partially see the image through the element. The transparency is not the issue, but I include this as I don't want a solution that makes the p take the full height of the .container and then repositions the text.
- It has to work in IE8 (only required browser).
- I can freely manipulate the html structure if needed, but I'd like to keep it as simple as possible.

I can do it trivially with javascript, but is it possible to do with pure CSS?

(this codepen shows partially what I'm trying to do: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sqjnz)

Edit for clarification: I want .container to be as tall as the tallest child (img or p). If both the img and p are present the text should be on top of the image and anchored at the bottom of .contianer so as it grows it covers more and more of the image. If there is no image (the img tag is not present) the box should behave like a normal div and expand to the same size as the p.

Comment: So the only problem I see here is how to position P at the bottom of your image. Container always is as high as the highest element as long as they're not floated. Is this what you're after?

Comment: @Robert Sorry for the poor description. I've update the question with a clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/B8Q5L/2) what you're after?

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100"/>
    <p>Heading</p>
</div>​
```

and CSS:

```
.container {
    /* these are just set so we can see the size of container */
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
.container img {
    margin-right: -100px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
.container p {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    line-height: 1em;
    color: #fff;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}​
```

And to accomodate IE into the mix with semi-transparency I suggest you read [Lea Verou's blog post](http://lea.verou.me/2009/02/bulletproof-cross-browser-rgba-backgrounds/).

Comment: Not exactly. If you look at the codepen you can see that the p stretches to the full width of the image no matter how big it is. I want this preferably without specifying a with on anything but the container. Your solution also does not work if I remove the img tag (the container collapses). Maybe it can't be done with pure css.

Comment: My apologies. It seems your solution works when I remove the img tag. I did something else to it first that broke it. Do you know why the image does not fill the height of the entire container? There seems to be a small (5ish pixel) gap below the image.

Comment: @Thomas: I suspect that small pixel gap is related to `p` and not `img`. I've updated my JSfiddle that resolves that as well. click the link in my answer and you should see updated display. both elements within container needed `vertial-align` to be set to bottom so they align with eachother.